# Конвертирование типа в (из) несколько других типов

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть необходимость представлять один тип в разные типы по мере необходимости. Как я понял, это можно делать средствами TypeConverter. Но что если нужно конвертировать тип в несколько других? Ведь TypeConverter может быть указан только один для класса.

Например необходимо приводить мой класс MyClass к int, string, bool в зависимости от ситуации.

Написал конвертер MyTypeConverter, переопределил у него методы CanConvertFrom() и ConvertFrom(). Указал в качестве атрибута своему классу

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
}
```

Конвертирование происходит в из bool в MyClass, как добавить возможности по конвертированию в другие типы?

Comment: Смотрите `System.Convert.ChangeType` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.changetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Для возможности само-конвертации в  [IConvertable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Конвертация из - не пробовал. Обычно делал напрямую конструкторы. Возможно оператор implicit поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не мешает при помощи одного `TypeConverter` производить конвертацию в различные типы.

Класс конвертера:

```
public class Converter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(int)
            || sourceType == typeof(string)
            || sourceType == typeof(bool))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(int)
            || destinationType == typeof(string)
            || destinationType == typeof(bool))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(int))
        {
            return 42;
        }
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return "String is fine for convertion";
        }
        if (destinationType == typeof(bool))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var sourceType = value.GetType();
        if (sourceType == typeof(int)
            || sourceType == typeof(string)
            || sourceType == typeof(bool))
        {
            return new Convertible() { ConvertionString = value.ToString() };
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Конвертируемый класс:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(Converter))]
public class Convertible
{
    public string ConvertionString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Проверка конвертации:

```
var source = new Convertible();
var intValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Convertible)).ConvertTo(source, typeof(int));
var stringValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Convertible)).ConvertTo(source, typeof(string));
var boolValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Convertible)).ConvertTo(source, typeof(bool));
Console.WriteLine(intValue); //42
Console.WriteLine(stringValue); //String is fine for convertion
Console.WriteLine(boolValue); //True

var fromIntValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Convertible)).ConvertFrom(42) as Convertible;
var fromStringValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Convertible)).ConvertFrom("String is fine for convertion") as Convertible;
var fromBoolValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Convertible)).ConvertFrom(true) as Convertible;

Console.WriteLine(fromIntValue.ConvertionString); //42
Console.WriteLine(fromStringValue.ConvertionString); //String is fine for convertion
Console.WriteLine(fromBoolValue.ConvertionString); //True
```